# Making ImageCardview in browse fragment totally transparent

Tags: android, leanback

I want to make my cardview totally transparent in browse fragment .But the problem is this default shadow type effect is coming.I have tried everything but its not going away.Anyway it can be removed.

```
CustomImageCardview cardView = new CustomImageCardview(mContext);
cardView.setFocusable(true);
cardView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
cardView.setElevation(0);
cardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext , R.color.transperent_color));
cardView.invalidate();
```

Thanx 
[image]

Comment: Hi atlast found the solution if anybody wants to know.ListRowPresenter has one property called setShadowEnabled (boolean enabled) which if set to false removes the shawdow.

Comment: You should put that as an answer and vote it like solved your question. Definitely is what I was looking for

Comment: Take a look to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624317/remove-background-from-imagecardview/42490914#42490914

Answer (score 1):

To make cards backgrounds totally invisible:
on instance of
`ListRowPresenter()` set those booleans falses

1. `selectEffectEnabled` (makes bottom rows' shadows invisible)
2. `shadowEnabled` (makes selected item's background invisible)

Answer (score 0):

CardView has default elevation which is why shadow is displaying. Override that using `cardElevation` property.

```
 app:cardElevation="0dp"
```

Comment: Where should I do that in code.I am using ImageCardView provided by android.If i use cardView.setElevation(0) its not working.

Comment: @prit Your question doesn't specify that it is an ImageCardView. Then update the question with relevant code also.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cardView.setCardElevation(0)`

Comment: The problem is image card view does not have any public api setCardElevation it has only setElevation which is not working.

Comment: how about creating a custom style with elevation 0 for that view, and using the style in the constructor ?

Comment: How about the Leanback library is terribly uncustomizable and confusing?